# How do I call my function in the for loop and update a dictionary with it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm doing an assignment and I am stuck on how to complete a particular section. The background is that I have created two functions, 
1) get_paths which has one parameter (input_folder), gets the full paths to .txt files in a certain folder 
2) get_basic_stats which has one parameter (txt_path), gets me the number of sentences, tokens, vocabulary and number of chapters in the text files in another folder

Now I am being asked to call the function get_paths, create an empty dictionary called bookstats, loop over the list of text files and call the function get_basic_stats on each file. Then I am supposed to print the output of calling the function on each file and update the dictionary with each iteration of the loop. I have to print the output on each file.There are 3 text files in the folder that I am supposed to investigate and this is the code I have so far

```
from utils import get_paths, get_basic_stats
final_output = get_paths("../Data/books")
print(final_output)

book2stats = {}

for text in final_output: 
    book2stats.update(get_basic_stats(text))

print(book2stats)
```

and this is the output

```
['../Data/books\\AnnaKarenina.txt', '../Data/books\\HuckFinn.txt', 
'../Data/books\\Macbeth.txt']
{'num_sents': 2050, 'num_tokens': 26224, 'vocab_size': 90, 
'number_of_chapters or acts': 6}
```

the output for get_paths works perfectly and shows me the 3 texts but when I try to do the for loop and update the dictionary I only get the output for the final text. currently lost on how else to proceed with this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"update the dictionary with each iteration"_ and then what? Add the numbers up? Store them separately for each text?

Comment: @Selcuk I believe I have to store them seperately for each text. These are the full instructions:

you first call the function get_paths
create an empty dictionary called book2stats, i.e., book2stats = {}
Loop over the list of txt files (the output from get_paths) and call the function get_basic_stats on each file
print the output of calling the function get_basic_stats on each file.
update the dictionary book2stats with each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: That problem statement is a bit vague and your interpretation doesn't make much sense. You can't have multiple elements having the same key in a dictionary. You may have a list of dicts and keep appending to the list instead of updating the dictionary.

Comment: @Loki Wrong question?

Answer (score 0):

dict: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

`dict.update()` takes a dict-like object as input. Each call to `dict.update(new_dict)` causes any keys in `dict` to be overwritten with keys from `new_dict`. Since `get_basic_stats` just returns a dict-like object, each call to `book2stats.update(get_basic_stats(text))` is just overwriting the keys of `book2stats` with the new values in the dict returned from `get_basic_stats(text))`. And that's what you're seeing

By "update", I'm going to assume that you want to update each of the integers that are in the dictionary. Right? That's the only possible way that this makes sense, to me.

```
final_output = get_paths("../Data/books")
book2stats = {}
for text in final_output: 
    # Fetch stats
    new_dict = get_basic_stats(text))
    # Print stats
    print(f'book: {text}, stats: {new_dict}')
    # Update stats
    for key, value in new_dict.items():
        # Increment all values by the new stats record
        book2stats[key] = book2stats.get(key, 0) + new_dict[key]
```

Or, I suppose you could mean that you want each text to have its own dictionary, and that these are themselves stored in a dictionary. So you'd have a dictionary mapping text names to dictionaries of stat names mapped to stat values. This would do that:

```
final_output = get_paths("../Data/books")
book2stats = {}
for text in final_output: 
    # Fetch stats for this new text
    book2stats[text] = get_basic_stats(text))
print(book2stats)
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
final_output = get_paths("../Data/books")
book2stats = {text : get_basic_stats(text) for text in final_output}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are updating dictionary - when you do dictionary.update, if the key exists it will automatically update the existing value. if not exists it will add as a new item.

My suggestion would be,

1. Use List instead of dictionary and add list.extend()
2. Along with value please add key also to the dictionary which should unique on each iteration

Sample code:

```
from utils import get_paths, get_basic_stats
final_output = get_paths("../Data/books")
print(final_output)

book2stats = []

for text in final_output: 
    book2stats.extend(get_basic_stats(text))

print(book2stats)
```